# Assets only correctly map up when my application isn't hosted on a pre-existing path

Tags: javascript, webpack, assets, webpack-file-loader

I'm developing an application for use on multiple client sites. These are hosted either as a subdomain or as a path (which I have no control over), like so:

1. https://application.example.com/#/example-page
2. https://example.com/application/#/example-page

Here is my Webpack 1 config:

```js
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff2?|eot|svg|ttf|md|jpg|png)$/,
      loader: 'file?name=[hash].[ext]'
    }
  ]
},
output: {
  path: __dirname + "/dist/build/",
  filename: "app.min.js"
}
```

With this, my assets get compiled into a `/build/` folder which also contains the main application JavaScript file:

[image: My dist/build folder]

The issue I'm having is that the compiled assets aren't found if the application is hosted on a pre-existing path (URL example 2 above) but load perfectly fine if no path exists. Doing some debugging reveals that for whatever reason the */build* directory must be specified for assets to load on the second URL example, but specifying */build* breaks the first URL example:

1. https://application.example.com/compiled-asset.png ✓
2. https://example.com/application/compiled-asset.png ⇐ 404
3. https://application.example.com/build/compiled-asset.png ⇐ 404
4. https://example.com/application/build/compiled-asset.png ✓

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the discussion about [output.publicPath](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) will be of help. Especially the note near the end about setting it at runtime.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thanks, whilst you were commenting I've just fixed it using the very same property. I was specifying a publicPath property as a previous test but that achieved nothing, however in appending `&publicPath=./build/` to the `loader` it now works perfectly on both URL types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the answer to this is to add the publicPath property to the `loader` itself as following:

```js
loader: 'file-loader?name=[hash].[ext]&publicPath=./build/'
```

I had previously attempted this with a separate `publicPath` property, but this didn't achieve anything.